# How to reference an item in a json object using another item inside the same object

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object with a number of items and want to be able to use one of the values inside of the object in order to get back the other item in the object.

I want to search the JSON Object with the "Abbv" then get back the "Set"

```
[
    {"Abbv": "VIS", "Set": "Visions"},
    {"Abbv": "5ED", "Set": "Fifth Edition"},
    {"Abbv": "POR", "Set": "Portal"},
    {"Abbv": "WTL", "Set": "Weatherlight"}
]
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Could you tell us what exactly the desired result would be in this example?

Comment: Loop through the list. If `element['Abbv']` matches what you're looking for, return `element['Set']`.

Comment: You have a regular Python list containing regular Python dicts. The fact that you might have gotten this by decoding a JSON value isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks guys, didnt think about iterating through it to get the desired response @Barmar was correct with what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
objects = [
    {"Abbv": "VIS", "Set": "Visions"},
    {"Abbv": "5ED", "Set": "Fifth Edition"},
    {"Abbv": "POR", "Set": "Portal"},
    {"Abbv": "WTL", "Set": "Weatherlight"}
]

for obj in objects:
    if obj['Abbv'] == 'VIS':
        print(obj['Set'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
json_objects = [
    {"Abbv": "VIS", "Set": "Visions"},
    {"Abbv": "5ED", "Set": "Fifth Edition"},
    {"Abbv": "POR", "Set": "Portal"},
    {"Abbv": "WTL", "Set": "Weatherlight"}
]

lookup = ('Abbv', 'POR')

for obj in json_objects:
    if lookup in obj.items():
        print(obj['Set'])  # 'Portal'
```

I suppose this is the result that you desire. You simply specify the pair lookup that you will search for and try to find it in the list of JSON objects. Once you've found it, access the `'Set'` key of this object.

Comment: I don't think this will work. `lookup in obj` tests whether `lookup` is a key of `obj`. But `lookup` is a dictionary, and the keys are strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no super short solution. You will have to iterate through the whole list, though you can short circuit if you find what you want.

You can do this using a function such as:

```
l = [
    {"Abbv": "VIS", "Set": "Visions"},
    {"Abbv": "5ED", "Set": "Fifth Edition"},
    {"Abbv": "POR", "Set": "Portal"},
    {"Abbv": "WTL", "Set": "Weatherlight"}
]
def search_for_abbv(abbv, l):
    """
    l: A list of dicts we want to search through.
    abbv: The abbreviation we want to find
    Returns None if nothing found else the abbreviation.
    """
    for item in l:
        if abbv == item['Abbv']:
            return item['Set']
temp = search_for_abbv('POR', l)
print(temp)
```

**Output:**

```
Portal
```

Note that I would probably use a list of `tuples` or a list of `namedtuples` if this is all you are doing to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just retrieving few values, then your best option would be wencakisa's answer. But if there's more to be done with data you might consider using pandas. In that case you can get wanted value like this:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [
    {"Abbv": "VIS", "Set": "Visions"},
    {"Abbv": "5ED", "Set": "Fifth Edition"},
    {"Abbv": "POR", "Set": "Portal"},
    {"Abbv": "WTL", "Set": "Weatherlight"}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
val = df.loc[df['Abbv'] == 'POR', 'Set']
print(val)
```